# Where to start with java as a backend with Google Closure?

Tags: java, google-closure

I like the look of Google Closure - I've been looking for something for a while that will let me share templates for AJAX as well as when the page loads. However, my background is PHP/Python, not Java for web programming.

Where should I start? I looked at spring once and it seemed massively complicated.

Is there a standard approach for using Google Closure with Java? I don't really know where to start on this one. I'm interested in tools for writing enterprise-grade, high traffic sites.

Thanks

Comment: Google closure is a javascript library. You don't need to know Java.

Comment: From http://code.google.com/closure/templates/: "Closure Templates are implemented for both JavaScript and Java, so that you can use the same templates on both the server and client side."

Comment: You can use templates on both the server and client. However, you don't have to do so. In fact, you don't have to use Closure Templates when using Closure. You can easily use Google Closure to write your javascript client code and use PHP/Python or whatever server side language you wish. That said, for anyone wanting to get started with Google Closure, I'd recommend this book [Closure: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920001416])